# из UTF-8 в windows-1251

Tags: java, utf-8, charset

Буду краток. Одна из проблем в моем сокет приложении на ява решилось тем что я кодировку исходного файла поменял с UTF-8 на windows-1251. Так вот многого ли я лишаюсь мало мне известной кадировки w1251? Будет ли поддерживать все англ,русские символы?

Comment: русские будут все конечно. каких то спец символов может не быть. посмотрите таблицу cp1251 и для себя решите. и не забывайте, что кроме windows есть другие ОС где 1251 не используется. А многого ли  лишаетесь ... ну как, в 1251 256 символов, с UTF-8 порядка миллиона ...

Comment: ajax запросы помоему только на UTF-8, еще могут быть проблемы с запросами в базу данных

Comment: кодировка - чистой воды условность. если вы пишите на java, то и бд у вас своя с вероятностью 99 процентов. а любая адекватная бд имеет настройки кодировки, так что тут проблем быть не должно. вопрос тут только один - зачем вы вообще меняли кодировку? исходя из вопроса это замена для замены